# How do I emulate MPC5xxx embedded microcontroller on QEMU?

Tags: qemu, powerpc

I've seen that QEMU can emulate PowerPC architectures, but in the documentation in the supported machines part I cannot find the MPC5xxx target, however it's mentioned as CPU type in the source code:
https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/7fe7fae8b48e3f9c647fd685e5155ebc8e6fb84d/target/ppc/cpu-models.c#L220

My question would be which command line arguments do I need to give to the qemu-system-ppc binary, or else how do I compile QEMU specifically to emulate MPC5xxx target? (on Linux host)
Do I need additional configuration? If yes, where do I find reference for it?

Answer (score 1):

I pulled the latest source:

```
$ git clone https://git.qemu.org/git/qemu.git
```

Then configured:

```
$ mkdir qemu-build
$ cd qemu-build
$ ../qemu/configure --target=ppc-softmmu
```

Then built:

```
$ make
```

I see these "mpc5xxx" CPU types listed:

```
$ ./qemu-system-ppc -cpu help | grep mpc5
PowerPC mpc5200_v10      PVR 80822011
PowerPC mpc5200_v12      PVR 80822011
PowerPC mpc52xx          (alias for mpc5200_v12)
PowerPC mpc5200          (alias for mpc5200_v12)
PowerPC mpc5200_v11      PVR 80822011
PowerPC mpc5200b_v21     PVR 80822011
PowerPC mpc5200b         (alias for mpc5200b_v21)
PowerPC mpc5200b_v20     PVR 80822011
```

I've never used these, but you'd use the command-line option "-cpu mpc52xx", for example.